# Cannot pass an object as props to another component in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, react-props

I'm trying to pass my useState object called "Shipping" from my AddressForm-component to the Review-component.

This is my object declaration in AddressForm-component and there is also an ChangeEvent function because the values that the shipping object gets are by inputfields.
Here is the full code for the AdressForm-component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import Review from './Review';
import "../../pages/pagesStyles/checkout.css";


export default function AddressForm() {
    const [shipping, setShipping] = useState({
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        address: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
        postalcode: "",
        country: "",
    })

    const updateField = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setShipping({
            ...shipping,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    const printValues = () => {
        console.log(shipping);
      };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Shipping address
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="firstname"
            name="firstname"
            label="First name"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="given-name"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.firstname}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="lastname"
            name="lastname"
            label="Last name"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="family-name"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.lastname}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="address"
            name="address"
            label="Address"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="shipping address-line1"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.address}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="city"
            name="city"
            label="City"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="shipping address-level2"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.city}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            id="state"
            name="state"
            label="State/Province/Region"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.state}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="postalcode"
            name="postalcode"
            label="Zip / Postal code"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="shipping postal-code"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.postalcode}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="country"
            name="country"
            label="Country"
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="shipping country"
            variant="standard"
            value={shipping.country}
            onChange={updateField}
          />
        </Grid>
        <button onClick={printValues}>Submit</button>
      </Grid>
        <div className='reviewComponent'>
            <Review data={shipping}/>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

In my Review-component, which should have received the props, I have done the following:

```
interface ShippingProps {
  data: {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    postalcode: string;
    country: string;
  };
}

function Review({data}: ShippingProps) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({data})
  }, [])
```

But when i console.log the data props, it says its undefined even though i have entered data in the inputfields for the shipping object.

Comment: could you share the jsx part where `updateField` is triggered?

Comment: The `console.log({data})` should not ever return `undefined` because `shipping` has a default value. Would need to see the entire components code to debug further. Unrelated note: you can use the `console.log()` outside of a `useEffect()` and you'll achieve the same functionality.

Comment: It's preferred that you edit your original post with updates to the question. My original suggestion for `<Review shipping={shipping}/>` was wrong so you can change that back for now, I see that in your updated code.

Comment: Try `<Review data={shipping}/>` instead of `<Review shipping={shipping}/>`

Comment: Ups sorry, that is also what it is now, i just tried your suggestion, but it still doesnt work with data.

Comment: It's not enough information to solve the problem. 

1. Remove the `useEffect` from the `Review` component and leave the `console.log` there. 2. include the entire `Review` component code in your question. 3. make sure you have no other `console.logs` that may be showing the `undefined`.